# Loading the error message of email validator

Tags: php

I'm trying to have a email validator in my program.

**My problem is every time I load the page I'm getting the error message "Email is not valid"**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if (!filter_var($EmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo "E-mail is not valid";
} else {
  $sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET fName='$fName', lName = '$lName', IdNumber='$IdNumber', Department='$Department', MobileNumber='$MobileNumber', EmailAddress='$EmailAddress', Username='$Username' WHERE idUser = '$idUser'";
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $success = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  }
  if ($success == TRUE) {
?>
<script>
  alert('You have successfully update account.');
</script>
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `$EmailAddress` set?

Comment: What's the content of it?

Comment: The only problem is the everytime i load the page, im getting the error message. But when im clicking the submit button it executes well.

Comment: email address is coming from post. But you didn't check form submitted or not before the email validation. So when you refresh, email is empty and it's throwing error message

Comment: It's likely not set on initial load.  You'd be better off checking to see if POST/GET data is sent first.

Comment: I guess the error is on my condition. But i dont know why -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it to safegaurd that:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' &&
    !filter_var($EmailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

This will only validate **when** you're operating off of a `POST` request to the page.

Comment: @PeeHaa, but if it's not a `POST` request, `$_POST` wouldn't be an empty array right? It truly wouldn't be set.

Comment: @Ralfh, I'm glad we could be of assistance!

Comment: If it is not a post request the `$_POST` superglobal *will* be an empty array

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal and is always set, even if it contains no information.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    // do stuff here
}
```